# Concave Curve With only CSS,A Compound Shapes in CSS

Tags: css

I have a CSS student and she is taking a CSS class,
and her teacher asked her to create a shape using only CSS codes,without any implementation of an Image.

the shape is a  Concave Curve,
is this possible?

the shape looks like this:

[image]

Actually I wonder about the Power of CSS3 at this point,because I have read somewhere that is not possible to create a concave curve or other complex rounded shapes in CSS,and I appreciate [imsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/361755/imsky) answer,but it's based on absolute positioning but,I need to know that is it possible to create such a shape without using positioning?

[This article](http://css-tricks.com/well-rounded-compound-shapes-css/) is about to show the creation of this kind of rounded shape using CSS,but it's not exactly the same shape,but it's useful for peoples whom interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/XXbJ5/

[image: curve]

HTML:

```
<div id="bg">
    <div id="bg-bottom"></div>
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bg {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative
}
#bg-bottom {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
    background:blue
}
#top {
    position:absolute;
    background:blue;
    top:0px;
    left:-100px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border-radius:100px
}
#bottom {
    position:absolute;
    background:white;
    top:0px;
    left:100px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border-radius:100px
}
```

Comment: Fantastic @imsky!!!,but could you please tell me is that possible to do it,without using positioning properties?

Comment: Any way you do it, you'll have to use positioning or shapes. Another way you can do it (not supported by most browsers) is a polygon `clip-path`, but otherwise you'll have to rely on what CSS provides.

Comment: Thanks A Lot @imsky,I wonder,why I am getting this down votes,I think it's an interesting question.

Comment: @Hbirjand this kind of question has been asked many times. It should have been considered as a duplicated question. Also this solution is not that perfect but it's all CSS can do. The cons here is the background of the parent should have solid color, in this case it is `white`, if you need a non-solid color (such as image background or gradient background), it won't work. Chec this http://jsfiddle.net/XXbJ5/1/

Comment: Thanks A Lot @King King,you fiddle working very nicely,actually I wonder about doing this,without the usage of absolute positioning.